# How to narrow the return type of array.groupBy in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote this groupBy function:

```
function groupBy<T>(arr: Array<T>, key: keyof T): Record<any, Array<T>> {
    const result = {} as Record<any, Array<T>>;

    for (const item of arr) {
        const groupKey = item[key];
        if (!result[groupKey]) {
            result[groupKey] = [] as any;
        }
        result[groupKey].push(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And I would like to narrow its return type to `Record<U, Array<T>>`, how can I do this?
Also, I would like to remove the `as any` that I added to put a compilation error under the rug.

Here is a [typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8AKgHwAUAhqqgFyICCV5BJANIgNYCmutXucwRIQCUtAEqcIcVABN85MLjYNUTIsWKIA3gFgAUAEgpYAM5REqTiZAAbcwF5tAX0TkTiCVNnzFyxsw0Abn19A2BpRFJjM0QYKE4AW0QBVyphbVCjBBi0DEwAaW5ERzjEgG0%20AF1gwwMYQVIAQktrOzLcrELcSvTdWoMW2yh29E7uSuLEMom3V0UagwMnTMG2joLxgDpMEBMAC1JShOEF5b1QyygQVCRVqBqzkL1o80pUSbL9RG1EMHIEzi0ABE5CBbHIyEBiAAjIgnCwvj8-gDgQAjMGuSG0WHwxFaX7-KFAiAYiFQgBMcIRem%20%20ORRJkpKxiEpuL01SeLwsViGk3WeAoVDYIMhQJO%20micBsnE2NjgyFId3FeiAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) The typescript signature is in the comments of the first answer. There is also [this](https://gist.github.com/robmathers/1830ce09695f759bf2c4df15c29dd22d)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but my question is about typing, not about the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by defining a type for the key you are grouping by and making sure the object type `T` has such a key and its value is a type compatible with `Record` allowed key types:

```js
function groupBy<K extends string, T extends { [key in K]: string | number | symbol }>(arr: Array<T>, key: K): Record<T[K], Array<T>> {
    const result = {} as Record<T[K], Array<T>>;

    for (const item of arr) {
        const groupKey = item[key];
        if (!result[groupKey]) {
            result[groupKey] = [];
        }
        result[groupKey].push(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8A0ogKYAeUJYAJgM6K1SoxjIA0iAKqRVXYgG9EAbQDWJXIhaJCAXQBcDJi2SIAPojAgAtgCMSqdQ1x64AG0QBfAHwAKAIapUigIJP7BTtY7jciwgCUigBKJBBwqNT4nMJyHG6oHtHW1oIAsABQAJDhYIyIqCS0IGZQiAC8gpaI9vSh4ZHRsbLx7p4pANyZmVnAEYi2ufkwlNqIcMA1TgHp2TkI%20WgYmIQSFVKjYhKyXXMwk7YAhIXFpcJLWKu4sjMCPVlZJyVQ5%20iX2%20vCO-eW909nFxW2wAdJgQLQABa2EYkbQBXZZX4ZHqFKAgVBIf5QXZI7oZIZlRyGSrCTKIQSaezaEiKABE9lpHHsyBpiAAjFY2GSKWAqazabpGTUWYoOZYuRlyUJedS6RAhczWQAmTnc6V8unUBUixAq8WZb7I-ELMpY9aAvAOJwceks2nwzJDcwkYFmODIWxYh0ZIA)